# Restructure JSON response in Javascript/Typescript/Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON data coming from a server as an API response. I want to restructure it for easy processing.

Input json file at assets/input-json.json in the stackblitz project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-87qser?file=src/assets/input-json.json

The output json that I want to have is at assets/output-json.json.

I think the conversion process is more related to typescript/javascript than angular, please help.

Comment: Please do not post only external sources in the question. The question becomes worthless when they go down.

Comment: What is output-json? Are you just renaming the file? (I haven't clicked the link btw)

Comment: It is a restructured json data, not the same file.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no magic ~ go to ~ way of doing this since it depends on your mapping patterns.

You can simply create a utility function that will take your input *JSON* and transform it to your output *JSON*:

```
function transform(input, output) {
    let output = {};
    output.transformedField = input.someField;
    // ...
    return output;
}
```